# How to get raw (url encoded) cookie value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

In Rails `cookies[:foo]` returns a decoded value of the cookie. How can I get the raw (url encoded) value of a cookie? I'm asking because Rails treats the `+` sign in cookie values as space, while I need it to be treated as the `+` character.

Comment: take a look at the `request` object or `request.headers` or `request.cookie_jar`

Comment: @Yule I found there nothing that would help me.

Comment: @Yule However `env["rack.request.cookie_string"]` is probably what I was looking for.